# Relationship method must return an object of type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am getting an error that suggests a problem with a relationship.

> Relationship method must return an object of type.

How do I fix this?

I have two tables

- **Batsmen:** id, name, countries_id
- **Country:** id, name

### My relationship

Batsmen model:

```
 public function countries(){
     $this->belongsTo('App\Country','countries_id');
 }
```

Country model:

```
 public function batsmen(){
     $this->hasMany('App\Batsmen');
 }
```

I am trying to get the country name to show on a batsmens profile with

```
<p>{{$batsmen->countries->name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to return the relationship like so :

```
 public function countries(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Country','countries_id');
    }

 public function batsmen(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Batsmen');
    }
```